# The given key was not found in the dictionary using ConnectToFacebook(); on C#

Tags: c#, facebook

I am trying to connect to facebook using this code:

```
    FacebookService MiFB = new FacebookService();
    string MyAppId = "xxxxxxxxx"
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MiFB.ApplicationKey = MyAppId;
        MiFB.ConnectToFacebook();
    }
```

and even I get "The given key was not found in the dictionary" on MiFB.ConnectToFacebook();

Please, can you help me?

Comment: which client are you using? also connecting to facebook is usually not that simple, I dont see any oauth tokens there, just having an api key wont grant you access to a user's info

Comment: I am using Visual C# Express 2010.
Before I tried another way using oauth tokens but didn't get anything only problems.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243286/oauthexception-200-user-must-have-accepted-tos-on-c-sharp-facebook

So as I understanded when I use ConnectToFacebook(); it should show a windows to allow permissions..

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this error happens when the library used as an OAuth/API helper is parsing either a JSON or an URL result, then converting it to a dictionary (i.e. `Dictionary<string, string>`), and is querying a specific value without verifying it exists, and without handling the error.

Inside the library, it probably does:

```
var the_Values_In_The_Form_Of_A_Dictionnary = Url.SomeParseUrlMethod(result);
var access_token = the_Values_In_The_Form_Of_A_Dictionnary["access_token"];
```

It seems several libraries used this path: DotNetOpenAuth, FlickrNet. And the one the OP used. Having t handler server error as real .Net error is frustrating. Throwing unhandled errors from good server results is a strange decision, or I'm missing the point about these libraries.